# subgroups for discrete x Axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a sub grouping in a ggplot2 (geom_point), meaning that I would like to shift discrete x values slightly according to a subgroup (see Figure).

I could achieve that by changing the discrete values to continuous and add a subgroup dependent shift value (see Fig.B), and than manually adjust the x labels. But I thought there is probably a more elegant way which deals with spacing and labeling issues.Below is a minimal example which hopefully describes what I mean.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    ID =       rep(seq(1,8),2),
    group =    rep(LETTERS[1:4],4),
    subgroup = c(rep("a",8),rep("b",8)),
    value = runif(16)
)
df$xpos <- as.numeric(df$group)+(as.numeric(df$subgroup)/4)


ggplot(data=df, aes(x=group, y= value, color=subgroup))+
  geom_point()+
    ggtitle("How it is")

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=xpos, y= value, color=subgroup))+
  geom_point() +
    ggtitle("How I would like it (without adjusted xAxes Labels)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `position_dodge`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=group, y= value, color=subgroup))+
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.5))+
  ggtitle("How it is")
```

[image]

---

*Data*

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
    ID =       rep(seq(1,8),2),
    group =    rep(LETTERS[1:4],4),
    subgroup = c(rep("a",8),rep("b",8)),
    value = runif(16)
)
```

Comment: thx, works like a charm.
As a follow-up question: Is there a way to combine that with a jitter on the x-scale?